# Least action principle and its quantum mechanical view

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, action

In Feynman's lecture (I am forgetting the volume number) while explaining the least action principle he mentions that the system actually follows all possible configuration paths. $\exp(iS/\hbar)$ superposes constructively for the values of action $S$ for which it is stationary with respect to the variations of the path. This argument is comprehensible but what is the actual quantum mechanical basis of this argument?

Comment: For a concise (if somewhat dated) exposition of this argument, see e.g. Feynman, R. P., "Principles of least action in quantum mechanics", [PhD Thesis, Princeton University (1942)](https://cds.cern.ch/record/101498/files/Thesis-1942-Feynman.pdf).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8663/2451