# Why must the propagator exponent be imaginary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, probability, propagator, unitarity

In response to [asmaier's question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8663/8007), [qmechanic showed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/8705/8007) why the propagator must be $\exp(cS)$.  That made perfect sense.  But can it also be shown that $c$ is imaginary?  I believe it follows from infinitesimal canonical transformation logic, since time is a canonical transformation, but I can't work it out.

Comment: if c is not purely imaginary, the propagation will not be unitary, meaning that probabilities will not add up to one.

Comment: For largely the same reasons Fourier transforms have imaginary exponents.

Comment: Do you know how to derive the path integral (Feynman’s argument)? The $e^{iS}$ in the path integral is coming from the $e^{-iH t}$ in the time-evolution operator. As a side note, the Euclidean time-evolution operator is $e^{-H t}$ which gives $e^{- S}$ in the path integral instead of $e^{iS}$ (if you don’t know anything about Euclidean field theory, ignore the last comment completely!)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: That the coefficient $c$ is imaginary is tied to unitary time-evolution, cf. above comment by naturallyInconsistent.

1. Here is one check: Show that the path integral $$\psi(x_f,t_f)~\sim~K(x_f,t_f;x_i,t_i)~=\int_{x(t_i)=x_i}^{x(t_f)=x_f}\!{\cal D}x~e^{cS[x]}$$ satisfies the [TDSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65489/2451) Phys.SE post. This calculation is sensitive to the correct normalization of the coefficient $c=\frac{i}{\hbar}$.
2. Alternatively, go with the standard textbook derivation of the path integral $$K(x_f,t_f;x_i,t_i)=\langle x_f,t_f;x_i,t_i\rangle$$ from the operator formalism, as Prahar suggests in above comment. See e.g. eq. (7) in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/56217/2451).