# Do non-Gaussian states always show negativity in phase space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, phase-space, wigner-transform, non-gaussianity

According to [Hudson’s theorem](http://www.google.com/search?q=hudson's+theorem), any pure quantum state with a positive Wigner function is necessarily a Gaussian state. In cases, in which the existing well-known Hudson
theorem immediately tells that the output state, which is non-Gaussian, must show negativity in phase space. Is the reasoning flawed?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It sounds like this: *"The theorem says X. Does X hold?"*.

Comment: You seem to be asking if "P implies G" does "not G imply not P"? Yes, this is simply the contrapostive statement

Comment: @ ACuriousMind If we consider all the states are pure. In such a case, the existing, well-known, Hudson theorem immediately tells that the output state, which is non-Gaussian, must show negativity in phase space?

Comment: @ ACuriousMind is that always true?

Comment: It still sounds to me as if you are simply asking whether the theorem is true (see Rod Vance's comment). Yes, yes it is. (Also, you must not leave a space after the @ if you want to notify me).

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I would like to know if there's any exception that non-Gaussianity of states with positive Wigner functions.

Comment: No, that is precisely what Hudson's theorem tells you: The Wigner function of a pure state is positive if and only if it is a Gaussian state.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I'm a bit confused with reading this paper [http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.79.062302](http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.79.062302)

Comment: The question is perfectly clear: Given a PURE quantum state with positive Wigner function, the state must be Gaussian. The obvious question is: What about MIXED quantum states? Can the theorem be extended to this case?

Answer (score 1):

See also my answer here: [Are negativity of the Wigner function and quantum behaviour equivalent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76202/are-negativity-of-the-wigner-function-and-quantum-behaviour-equivalent/103332#103332)

It seems that it is not clear whether the theorem can be extended to all kinds of mixed states. As you say, given a pure state, if we know that it is not Gaussian, Hudson's theorem implies that its Wigner function must be negative somewhere.

For states not covered by the theorem, nothing of this sort can be said. As far as I know, the question whether Hudson't theorem holds for all mixed states has not been settled yet.