# What is Wave Function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

Well, what is the meaning of wave function? What does it represent? In Schrodinger's equation, we find the value of Ψ. But what is Ψ exactly? Max Born only gave an explanation of what $Ψ^2$ (the probability of particle with low mass enough to have an observable wavelength to be in a position in space). But no one knows what Ψ is.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8062/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a direct physical interpretation for the complex wavefunction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9109/)

Answer (score 1):

The *name* for what the wave function represents is “probability amplitude”. You should simply consider that a fundamental physical quantity (at least in non-relativistic QM), no more or less mysterious than “electric field”. Electric field is three real numbers at each point in space. Probability amplitude (for one particle) is one complex number at each point in space. Why? Because this is how Nature seems to work. Do we really “know” what electric field or probability amplitude *is*? No. We just learn how they *work*.

Physics builds *mathematical models* of reality. What reality *is* is probably unknowable or meaningless, and more philosophy than physics.