# Why is the wave function complex?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers

[image: This is the image of the paragraph from the book]

Why should an equation ([TDSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation)) in which first time derivative is related to second space derivative have a solution that contains $i$?The wave function is supposed to be complex, but I am unable to understand why it can also be assumed to be complex directly from my previous statement as stated in Quantum Physics by [Eisberg & Resnick](http://www.google.com/#q=Eisberg+Resnick). Can anyone help me develop an intuition?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8062/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

A first answer that cames to my mind is "why shouldn't it?".

More seriously (if your question is serious). First, you should notice that the original version of TDSE is $$i\hbar\dot\psi = H\psi$$ so you actually already have an $i$ there. However, notice that this is not required to have complex solutions. For example, the equation (second order in space)
$$ \frac{d^2f}{dx^2} = -af $$
has absolutely real coefficients, but also has complex solutions, for example of the kind $$ Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix}$$
You might be interested in knowing that those can also be written in real form as a linear combination of sine and cosine.