# Are complex numbers really needed in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, complex-numbers, linear-algebra

I have been studying some Lie theory recently and I came across the idea of representing complex numbers using matrices, e.g.
$$1=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
,
i=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then everything involving complex numbers can be converted into a problem of 2 by 2 matrices. For example, a 2 by 2 spin matrix can be converted into a 4 by 4 real matrix in the following way:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a+id & -b-ic\\
b-ic & a-id\\
\end{pmatrix}
\longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -d & -b & c\\
d & a & -c & -b\\
b & c & a & d\\
-c & b & -d & a\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The determinant is preserved using the rule for block matrices:
$$
\det 
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D\\
\end{pmatrix}
=\det(AD-BC),
$$
and the eigenvalue problem follows in a similar manner.

**For me it seems a legit formulation of QM without using complex numbers, but I was always told by my professor that QM ***requires*** complex numbers. Is there anything I am missing here or is my professor wrong?**

Related questions:

- [QM without complex numbers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32422/qm-without-complex-numbers)
- [About the complex nature of the wave function?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8062/about-the-complex-nature-of-the-wave-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QM without complex numbers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32422/)

Comment: Not going to check your math, but if it works, then it is _isomorphic_ to complex number arithmetic. So, IMO, your professor maybe is being a bit narrow-minded.

Comment: Your professor is wrong, the complex numbers are only a super short way to express things, they are isomorphic to R^2. I am not sure about using matrices but it seems plausible at first sight

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I believe the wave function at a point can be represented as a 2 by 2 real matrix too.

Comment: P.S., Benefit № 1 to using complex arithmetic: The notation provides a compact and elegant way to describe periodic motion (e.g., waves). Benefit № 2: It's an extension of real arithmetic, so the notation and the algebraic rules already are familiar to students who are just learning it.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense since people started using complex numbers before matrices.