# Imaginary numbers in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, mathematics, complex-numbers

Do imaginary numbers in quantum mechanics do anything different than, say, a regular 3D coordinate system? Why do they show up in e.g the Schrödinger Equation? Is it because "i" can model waves *and* circular motion (e^i(pi) iirc)? If so, do complex and imaginary values do anything different than a sine or cosine function? Sorry if this sounds like alot, I'm just confused why imaginary quantities are showing up in physics.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8062/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Imaginary numbers are about as imaginary as $e$ or $\pi$. It's very unfortunate nomenclature that we are stuck with for historical reasons.